# What are the visa requirements of Malaysia for Spanish citizens in 2015?

Tags: visas, malaysia, spanish-citizens

As a Spanish national, do I need a visa to visit Malaysia?

I yes, can I get a Visa on arrival (at the airport if arriving by plane, or at the border if arriving by bus/train) ?

Comment: As a general tip, instead of trusting random websites, you can always check visa information on Timatic: it's what the airlines use, so it's virtually always up to date. http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/

Comment: Thanks, that's a great tip. I did come across Timatic before but I could not figure out how to use it for free, the demo does not seem to work (tried it on chrome & firefox) https://www.timaticweb.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Spanish citizen, one does **not seem** to need a visa to stay in Malaysia up to 3 months (90 days I suppose, the exact number of days is not specified on the website for some reason).

The [website of the Embassy of Malaysia in Madrid](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/esp_madrid/requirement_foreigner) has a very strange page saying first "VISA REQUIREMENT BY COUNTRY, please click the following websites, www.imi.gov.my or www.kln.gov.my", & then displaying information about "SINGLE ENTRY VISA VALID FOR 14 OR 30 DAYS". I chose to ignore the last info & go to the [www.imi.gov.my](http://www.imi.gov.my) which is the website of the Immigration Department in Malaysia.

The [relevant page on the website of the Immigration Department in Malaysia](http://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/main-services/visa/visa-requirement-by-country) does **not** mention Spain as one of the nationalities when a visa is needed. The only conclusion I can draw is that Spanish nationals don't need a visa for Malaysia.

See also the [Wikipedia list of Visa requirements per country for Spanish citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Spanish_citizens) - although you should always triple check what is mentioned here with what official authorities say.